# Turtle function draws a line even after using penup when I label coordinate axis

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to use penup and pendown function to prevent the turtle drawing the line while I move a position to label coordinate points on the x-axis and y-axis respectively. But to my surprise it stills draws the line. Below the line of code that appears buggy!

```
        alex.penup()
        alex.setpos(index-10,300-20) #Line appears even after lineup
        alex.pendown()
        alex.write(label,font=("Arial", 10, "normal"))
```

Below is the source code - https://replit.com/join/gtywdtyqia-uditswaroopa

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVpPC.png)

Comment: As noted in the answer - the source code isn't accessible without a log-in. Try and share a minimal example of code that fully demonstrates the problem you are having. But otherwise, good question.

Answer (score 1):

Your source code on replit.com requires a login so folks may not be able to examine it -- please include it in your question.

The code you show looks fine, but it's the pen moving to where the label is to be written.  I suspect the lines may be getting drawn when the turtle returns from writing the label, i.e. the next line of code you don't show:

```
    alex.penup()
    alex.setpos(index-10,300-20)
    alex.pendown()
    alex.write(label,font=("Arial", 10, "normal"))
    alex.goto(index,300)
```

Although you could wrap this `goto()` with another `penup()`, the `write()` method doesn't require the pen to be down, so try leaving the pen up the entire time you're writing all the labels.